# Копирование изображения из объекта Canvas

Tags: canvas, java, bitmap

Есть некоторый экземпляр класса Canvas. Мне нужно скопировать изображение этого Canvas в другой Canvas или же в другой Bitmap для дальнейшего копирование в Canvas командой

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,paint);
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Не нашёл, как скопировать из Canvas в Bitmap, но зато нашёл, как скопировать из одного Canvas в другой.

    
 public void copyCanvasFromAnother(Canvas from, Canvas to){
  Picture pict=new Picture();
  pict.draw(from);
  to.drawPicture(pict);
 }

Comment: Проверил на машине - не робит(